# Get data from another computer using sqlite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Now, i am planning to have 1 main computer and 2 client computer in the same domain. I want to run a form application in the main computer that uses [Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) database. Then I want to query some data in the main computer from client computers. What would be your suggestions about those 2 questions of mine:

1. What is the best way to implement this server-client structure to communicate computers.
2. What is the best way to get a big datatable from main computer that uses sqlite.

I am using .Net Framework 4.0 for Form applications.

Comment: Why sqlite instead of another sql platform?

Comment: Sqlite may not be the best choice if you are doing concurrent connections.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz; I have to use an embedded and serverless sql plstform. Do you mean another embedded sql?

Answer (score 0):

you may share the directory, either via Netbios (aka samba, for linux users) or nfs.

however, this is not a good idea, since sqlite locks the file, this may break your implementation if the filesystem fails for whatever reason. you might want to use a real distributed architecture, helping concurrency and load balancing.

another way would be to use sqlite, but proxy it through a web service, made by you specifically for this. it will serve the requests, and it would be run in the same server where you want the sqlite file, so you can avoid sharing the file/directory containing the database

Comment: Directory sharing would not be a good idea i think. Best way would be a web service.

Comment: i strongly agree :) just suggested it to "technically" answer your question :) note that using a web service will only help you to not share the file/dir, but you would still have concurrency issues i guess

Comment: I could hang the other calls while having another client calls from web service.

Comment: i think this will happen "automagically" do to sqlite calling the flock() in the underlying os. anyway, this would mean that the 1st client will not have to wait, but the 2nd will. the 3rd would have to wait for the 1st and 2nd to complete (if you're coding some kind of fifo).. but think about the 10th client.. i dont know the exact extent of your particular requirements, but it may slow down things a bit (or a lot.. )

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a WCF service that serializes and deserializes  *commonly shared* model/domain objects. WCF sends it across the wire.